# Spring Integration - Log time taken for whole file processing

Tags: spring, performance, logging, spring-integration

I have a scenario to split a large files to small chunks using File Inbound, Splitter, Transformer and File Outbound adapter. I would like to know how long it took to process the file starting from read to split to write back. How do I achieve this functionality?

Any help is appreciated.

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="/Documents" filename-pattern="test.txt" channel="inputFiles">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="0"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="inputFiles">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor"/>
</int:channel>

<int:splitter
        input-channel="inputFiles"
        output-channel="output" ref="multiTaskFileSplitter" method="splitMessage" apply-sequence="true">
</int:splitter>


<int:channel id="output">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="executor1"/></int:channel>

<file:outbound-channel-adapter mode="APPEND" channel="output" auto-create-directory="true" delete-source-files="true" directory="/splitter" filename-generator="fileNameGenerator">
</file:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Regards
Karthik

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `ChannelInterceptor` and `MessageHeaders` modification in the beginning of the flow - adding some `currentTime` header. And calculation the spent time in the end of flow. It can be done with the same `ChannelInterceptor`, too.

Starting with the Spring Integration 4.2 we have now `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice` which can be applied to the `<poller>`'s of the `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` for the same `currentTime` header addition logic.

Comment: Great, I would love to check on Advice. Reason being, after the last channel still I will be in processing the file which is not accounted with first option.

Comment: Sorry, not sure in your last sentence. Please, re-phrase or show and describe the code snippet on the matter.

Comment: I added the code in my original question, what I am communicating is file-outbound will still writing files from channel = output where we will be having the end time using interceptor which will not account for the time spent by outbound adapter. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Well, you explanation is still unclear. I don't see any `ChannelInterceptor` stuff in your code. You can overcome the `outbound-channel-adapter` one-way issue with the `postSend` implementation. Which is invoked exactly after the `handleMessage`. If you are worry about *all* your files, you should take a look to more complex solution with the `aggregator`, but anyway the trick is the same - `MessageHeader` to track the time.

Comment: Thanks for your time Artem

Comment: Is there any way to log the process time without editing the xml file?

Comment: Yes, coding with Java, but still you have to write something anyway. The mentioned `ChannelInterceptor` can be added into the `AbstractMessageChannel` at runtime.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I've tried to enriched the headers with ".enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("startTime", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))", but it gives me a starting time when I start the application. I want to fetch the current time in the beginning of every new triggered process and put that in the header. Is that possible? I don't find proper examples with ChannelInterceptor without using xml files.

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for a new SO question! I can't read code from the comments here. Sorry

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49924806/logging-process-in-spring-integration-without-using-xml-files