# Java spring integration gateway request response time logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using spring integration gateway for exposing a rest service. It has request-channel and reply-channel configured. I am looking for configuration that give me the time taken for each rest operation.

Below is the gateway configuration:

```
<int:gateway id="testServiceGateway"
         service-interface="com.test.ws.TransactionServices"
         default-reply-time-out="5000"
         error-channel="txErrorChan">
     <int:method name="evaluateTransaction"
             request-channel="tranRequestChan"
             reply-channel="tranResponseChan"
             reply-time-out="3000" />
</int:gateway>
```

For example: I used custom request-handler-advice-chain for  kafka-outbound-channel-adapter. Looking for something like this for gateway?

Comment: Maybe you can check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213467/spring-integration-log-time-taken-for-whole-file-processing

Comment: What is your configuration so far?

Comment: @Artem,  this is my current gateway configuration.     <int:gateway id=“testServiceGateway” service-interface=“com.test.ws.TransactionServices” default-reply-time-out=“5000” error-channel=“txService”><int:method name=“evaluateTransaction” request-channel=“tranRequestChan” reply-channel=“tranResponseChan” reply-time-out=“3000” /></int:gateway>

Comment: Please, don't place bug code snippets in the comments. Would be better to edit your question with an appropriate formatting.

Comment: See how I formatted you question to make it readable for other people. Please, learn how to post over here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @ArtemBilan, apologies as I was using mobile browser. corrected and pasted now. Please let me know if this helps

Comment: It's OK. Let me now to think about an answer for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you talk about a REST call you probably can think about using a *tracing* tool like Spring Cloud Sleuth: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-sleuth/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#http-client-integration

Although for your so simple use-case I would just take a current time before calling that `TransactionServices.evaluateTransaction()` method and after to calculate a whole call period.

You can also follow my recommendations in the mentioned answer for the [Spring Integration - Log time taken for whole file processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32213467/spring-integration-log-time-taken-for-whole-file-processing). So, you can inject a `startTime` header in the interceptor for the `tranRequestChan` and calculate in the interceptor for the `tranResponseChan`.

Another way is to rely on the Micrometer metrix on the channels or `MessageHandler`s: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/system-management.html#mgmt-channel-features

Comment: Thanks Artem, second option to inject a header looks good to me. Third option require a jmx access. Thanks for your solution.

Comment: Yes, I know that third option is slightly involving, but even with the second option you need to determine how to get access to that calculated period if you need to do with it something more rather than just logging.